# How to recover the encrypted data after a hard reset of a moto G8

Tags: google

I forgot my pattern to unlock my moto G8 so I decided to make a hard reset to access it; which I successfully did and gained access into my phone. I never had any data in the sd card nor google drive; I got access  to my Gmail acct, photos app etcetera; but then I realize that some apps like google messages, whats app, and some others didn't show the previous data or messages.
After trying to get that data I found that google has that old data encrypted and is asking me for the pattern (Which I forgot and that's the reason that I did the hard reset!!) I tried to get encrypted data using the new pattern with no success and i also used what I think was the old pattern but finally I got a warning saying that I have only 3 more chances to try the pattern before the data will be wiped off.
Does anyone of you guys know how to recover that encrypted data?